# Event(pop-up) on the client

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, websocket, popup

I have a bit weird requirement - the scenario is as follows :

1. Many users will be logged into a web application which is a legacy *JSP-Servlets app*. with client code written in pure JS and some DWR. The app. server is **IBM WAS 7.x**. There is a load balancer and two web servers in between. **The application supports only IE**
2. The app. will have a new web service which will be called by some third party app. quite frequently
3. Whenever this ws is called, the web app receives and stores some data. When this happens, a pop-up must appear in the **RELEVANT** user's browser(session) notifying him about the new data received via the ws
   By **RELEVANT** I mean suppose 10 users(10 sessions) from diff. locations are logged in but the new data is relevant only to 4 users(4 sessions), only those 4 users must receive the pop-up.
4. **I want to avoid the awful 'polling js' code** :(

I read about the [web sockets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html) but I'm not sure if EE 5 supports that and given the set-up(point 1), web sockets will work. How shall I proceed ?

Comment: EE 5 does not include websocket - JSR 356; that was introduced in EE 7. Seems like (unless you can change your environment), you will have to use some kind of polling, look for jsonp and alternatives..

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'jsonp and alternatives' ?

Comment: sure, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP ,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling + google queries on that topic..